# minimum number of nodes that traverse all the graph

Tags: graphs, algorithm-analysis, data-structures, runtime-analysis

In the following graph, we can traverse entire graph if we select the nodes 0 and 2. I am looking for an efficient algorithm which returns this two nodes. Note that this is neither vertex-cover problem nor dominating-set problem since we don't need to select node 3. We say that, if we select node 0, we can go to node 1 from there and if we select node 2, we can go to node 3 and then node 4 from there.

Also, the number of nodes can be up to 10^5 and the algorithm's runtime must be 1 second or less. Any suggestion would be useful.

[image: graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try combining [Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan's_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) with a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

Comment: I have implemented a SCC algorithm and now I have number of  components and know which node in which component. Now I need to create a new graph I think, to apply topological sort on it. Right? However, I can't figure out how to create the new graph? A little bit help please?